Proving the subspaces in two affine subsets are equal
I have a proof for Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right 3.E Q7 but I'm not sure about its correctness or how to simplify it.
Q) Suppose $v, x$ are vectors in $V$, and $U, W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $v + U = x + W$. Prove that $U = W$.
My working
Let basis of $U$ be $u_1, ..., u_m$, and extend to a basis of $V$ to make $u_1, ..., u_m, v_{m+1}, ..., v_n$, and let the basis of $W$ be $w_1, ... w_p$
Because $v + U = x + W$, we can say that $(v-x) + U = W$. Let $(v-x) = \gamma_1u_1 + ... + \gamma_mu_m + \gamma_{m+1}v_{m+1} + \gamma_nv_n$, then we have that $(\gamma_1u_1 + ... + \gamma_mu_m + \gamma_{m+1}v_{m+1} + \gamma_nv_n) + (a_1u_1 + ... + a_mu_m) = b_1w_1 + ... + b_pw_p$
We can simplify this to $(z_1u_1 + ... + z_mu_m) + (\gamma_{m+1}v_{m+1} + ... + \gamma_n v_n) = b_1w_1 + ... + b_pw_p$ (where $z_i = \gamma_i + a_i$)
Therefore $\text{span}(u_1, ..., u_m) + \text{span}(v_{m+1}, ..., v_{m}) = \text{span}(w_1, ..., w_p)$, therefore $U \subset W$
Then repeating this argument, but changing the first step to take $U = (x-v) + W$ and making $V$'s basis an extension of $W$'s instead of $U$'s, we get that $W \subset U$
Therefore because $W \subset U$ and $U \subset W$, then $U = W$.
Questions

I am not sure if the conclusion that $U \subset W$ and vice versa is a valid step
Am I able to 'split' the affine subset $x + W$ to bring $x$ to the other side and state that $(v-x) + U = W$?
Is there a simpler way to write out this proof without expanding out all the basis vectors of each subspace?



Note that for any $a,b \in V$, and any subset $S \subset V$, $a+(b+S) = (a+b)+S$. So add $-x$ to both sides of $v+U = x+W$.

You don't need an explicit basis. You have $v-x+U=W$, and since $0\in W$, we have $x-v \in U$, hence $v-x \in U$ and so $v-x+U=W$, from which the result follows.



I see. So because there is always some $u \in U$ such that $v - x + u = w$, and there exists $0 \in W$, so there is some $u$ that $v - x = -u$, therefore $x - v$ and $v - x$ are in $U$. Therefore, $(v-x) + U$ is just $U$, and because we are given that $(v-x) + U = W$, we have $U = W$.

@krm2233 That is not correct, all you know is that $v-x$ lies in $U$ (or $W$), not that $v=x$. With the real line, $1+\mathbb{R} = 0+\mathbb{R}$, but $1 \neq 0$.

@copper.hat sorry, you're absolutely right. What I meant to say was that in Axler's terminology, $v+U=x+W$ is equivalent to $(v-x)+U=W$, so that $W$ is a translate of $U$. But the translates of $U$ are disjoint or equal, hence the fact that $0\in W$ implies that $W=(v-x)+U=U$, and hence $(v-x)+U = U$, or $v+U=x+U$.
